# No method for Switching to iframe in mobile web using AppiumLibrary in robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I need to switch to an iframe in mobile web, but there is no method in AppiumLibrary to do so.
If I add SeleniumLibrary, then certain methods present in AppiumLibrary and SeleniumLibrary conflicts, For Ex :

```
*** Settings ***
Library  AppiumLibrary
Library  SeleniumLibrary
Resource  ../Tests/basetest.robot

*** Test Cases ***
Open_App

    Open iOS Mobile Web App
    go to url   ${URL}
    wait until element is visible //iframe  timeout=10
    select frame    //iframe[1]
    wait until element is visible   body>button   timeout=10
    click element   body>button
```

But, I am getting the following error :

```
fanilsuratwala$ robot Tests/Launch.robot
==============================================================================
Launch                                                                        
==============================================================================
Open_App                                                              | FAIL |
No keyword with name 'wait until element is visible //iframe' found. Did you mean:
    AppiumLibrary.Wait Until Element Is Visible
    SeleniumLibrary.Wait Until Element Is Visible
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Launch                                                                | FAIL |
1 test, 0 passed, 1 failed
==============================================================================
Output:  /Users/fanilsuratwala/PycharmProjects/Automation/output.xml
Log:     /Users/fanilsuratwala/PycharmProjects/Automation/log.html
Report:  /Users/fanilsuratwala/PycharmProjects/Automation/report.html
```

Comment: You have a typo, just one space between "visible", and "//iframe"

Comment: Yes, now i dont get that error, but getting different error at "select frame" line, that says : No browser is open..How to share the driver instance to SeleniumLibrary?. The first 3 lines of the test case uses AppiumLibrary.

Answer (score -1):

You should always use the library name for the conflicting keywords.

The error message gives you the suggestions. Just pick the
`SeleniumLibrary.Wait Until Element Is Visible`.